# PHP plural gettext with formatted numbers

Tags: php, multilingual, gettext

I want to be able to format a (multilingual) sentence like:

`I have 12,345 widgets.`

In my .po I have

```
msgid "I only have %d widget."
msgid_plural "I have %d widgets."
msgstr[0] "I don't have any widgets."
msgstr[1] "I only have %d widget."
msgstr[2] "I have %d widgets."
```

`ngettext("I only have %d widget.", "I have %d widgets.", 12345);`

If I use `number_format(12345)` I get back a string of `"12,345"`, which can't be used to detect plurals ([the docs say that it must be an `int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ngettext.php)).

Is there a way I can have the `gettext` serve up a formatted number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` in combination with `number_format` like:

```
sprintf(ngettext("I only have %s widget.", "I have %s widgets.", 1), number_format(1, 0, '.', ','));
sprintf(ngettext("I only have %s widget.", "I have %s widgets.", 999), number_format(999, 0, '.', ','));
sprintf(ngettext("I only have %s widget.", "I have %s widgets.", 1000), number_format(1000, 0, '.', ','));
```

This will return:

```
I only have 1 widget.
I have 999 widgets.
I have 1,000 widgets.
```